# From a tuple list, Insert tuples Index[0] and Index[1] into a function

Tags: python, function, tuples, iteration

Good mooring  to all,

The objective is to be able to create a series of new columns by inserting x and y into the df[f'sma_{x}*Vs_sma*{y}'] function.

The problem that I’m having is that I’m only getting the last tuple value into the function and therefore into the data frame as you can see on the last image.

On the second part of the code,  3 examples on how the tuples values must be plug into the function. IN the examples I will be using the first 2 tuples (10,11), (10,12) and the last tuple (48,49)

Code:

```
a = list(combinations(range(10, 15),2))
print(a)

for index, tuple in enumerate(a):
    x = tuple[0]
    y = tuple[1]
    print(x, y)

df[f'sma_{x}_Vs_sma_{y}'] = np.where(ta.sma(df['close'], lenght = x)  > ta.sma(df['close'], lenght = y),1,-1)
```

Code Examples:

Tuple (10,11)

```
df[f'sma_{10}_Vs_sma_{11}'] = np.where(ta.sma(df['close'], lenght = 10)  > ta.sma(df['close'], lenght = 11),1,-1)
```

Tuple (10,12)

```
df[f'sma_{10}_Vs_sma_{12}'] = np.where(ta.sma(df['close'], lenght = 10)  > ta.sma(df['close'], lenght = 12),1,-1)
```

Tuple (13,14)

```
df[f'sma_{13}_Vs_sma_{14}'] = np.where(ta.sma(df['close'], lenght = 13)  > ta.sma(df['close'], lenght = 14),1,-1)
```

[Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDIPD.png)

Comment: As a general rule, if your editor turns your variable name a different color than the other variable names, the variable name chosen may give you some weird behavior because it is already in use.  I would change the name of `tuple` in your for loop.  It may not be related to your issue but if you use `tup` or something else it will be safer.  `tuple` is also the name of a builtin function to create a tuple.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments, if you may show me a simple example I really appreciate it, I´m new in python and this issue is taking a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

On the next lines the code that solve the issue. Although looking backwards seams very easy, it took me some time to get to the answer.

Thanks to the people that comment on the issue

```
a = list(combinations(range(5, 51),2))
print(a)

for x, y in a :
  df[f'hma_{x}_Vs_hma_{y}'] = np.where(ta.hma(df['close'], lenght = x)  > ta.hma(df['close'], lenght = y),1,-1)
```